# Pythonic way to determine OS distribution RHEL, CentOS or SUSE

Tags: python

Is there any pythonic way to determine OS distribution/flavor?

cat /etc/issue shows me following -- [its CentOS 5.6]

```
[root@localhost Abhishek]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Comment: open that file and read it?

Comment: Is your question intended to be restricted to just RHEL, CentOS and SUSE, or could it be Windows, BeOS, MacOS, *BSD, Plan 9 or VMS, too?

Comment: It is specific to unix only.. and I want better Pythonic way..

However, thanks @soon I got the answer in the post you mentioned
Its - platform.linux_distribution()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sys.platform()` to get the platform.
Or for more detailed information use [platform.platform()](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.platform)

```
>>> import platform
>>> print platform.linux_distribution()
('Ubuntu', '12.04', 'precise')
```

**Note**: [`platform.linux_distribution()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#unix-platforms) has been deprecated since Python 3.5, and will be removed in Python 3.7.